# Get text between tags PHP

Tags: php, xml, text, tags

I have this html line:

```
<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="1923-12">December 1923</time> (USA)
```

How can i retrieve only   "December 1923 (USA)"   from that code by using PHP?

Comment: See [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/1396314)

Comment: It's basically `strip_tags`, however you are invited to use the search of this site. I mean, can you imagine this question has not been asked before?

Comment: Do you want to do it the proper way by parsing the XML or do you want to just remove all tag data from that short string?

Comment: I've done it.Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use strip_tags() in php

```
echo strip_tags('<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="1923-12">December 1923</time> (USA)');
```

Comment: Please do not anser to these trivially and obviously duplicate questions. Please.

Comment: @hakre: In most cases, I would agree with you, but this time, the OP doesn't have to use a DOM parser, he can simply strip_tags(); this seems to be different from the other questions on this topic.

Comment: Man, there are tons of duplicate questions to this. I did not say strip_tags is *the* solution, instead I try to invite the OP to search for that topic a little so s/he can choose from the wide variety of answers that are available.

Comment: @Chris Don't forget to click on the check mark at the left side of answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to strip the tags. You have more than that line in your string, right?

Use regular expressions for this:

```
$time = preg_replace('/<time.*?>(.*?)<\/time>/s', '$1', $str);
```

Edit: I just read that you want to get the trailing string "(USA)". Okay, strip_tags() would fit your expectations.

Comment: Well you only did half of the job with your answer. I suggest you execute the code and compare with the requested outcome if you actually consider to answer this question.

Comment: I have only this line. Thanks.

Comment: @hakre: Do not be so aggressive. Read my edit above. (I edited before you commented.)

Comment: I'm pro-actively defensive passively agressive you could say, okay ;), but actually, I'm writing some comment. I won't consider that an agressive action.

Comment: I just meant, here at Stack Overflow, we don't have to do the complete job for the OP. We should only show the correct way or just give the OP some tips.

Comment: You mean in form of a comment that the question is a duplicate and `strip_tags` does the job? [Like this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070896/get-text-between-tags-php#comment14490065_11070896)

Comment: Please compare the posting time of your comment and my answer. I answered about 4 minutes before you. An answer won't be more correct when you answer twice.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't want just what's between the tags, but what's not in the tag: you can use php's [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

Comment: Please do not anser to these trivially and obviously duplicate questions. Please.